# Save Users Input in a Variable, and Post that Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, variables, input

I have a small form and When I click the Join button, and enter my information, I want it to save the value of the Username form, and then replace the Join and Signup button with their name or "Hello" + name.

So I have a JSFiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/LCBradley3k/t3HF5/
I would think it would be something like the following code, but that doesn't work:

```
var name  = document.getElementById("name");
```

Then I would want it to put name in some type of div that replaces the two button at the top.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery (which your jsfiddle indicates you are), this should be fairly trivial.

```
var name = $('#name').val();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Now where exactly would this go in the JSFiddle? Also, how would I add the value to a div, so I could position it, etc...?

Comment: Not sure what you need it for exactly, but I would use it to grab the inputted value by the user whenever they click the buton  $('#join').on('click', function().  And what do you mean by add the value to a div?  If you want to add a value to something, do $('#name').val('here's the value'), which in this case is not advisable since it is a user input field.

Comment: Reread your post again.  It looks like once you have the name field, target the ID of the div and place the content there.  $('#divID').html(name); for instance.

Comment: Also take a look at .serialize especially if you're working with forms with lots of fields it makes life much easier when collecting values and serializing them ready for posting: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 1):

Using pure javascript (no jQuery), if it's an input element, to get the input value use:

```
var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
```

To replace a div's content with `name`:

```
document.getElementById("div_id").innerHTML=name;
```

You can also use html:

```
document.getElementById("div_id").innerHTML="<p>" + name + "</p>";
```

Or replace the div's value:

```
document.getElementById("div_id").value=name;
```